# How can I compare scores using if statement and .innerText?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, addeventlistener

I'm trying to make a Ping Pong scoreKeeper. Everything is done except the part where the scores are compared and a winner is declared. I'm trying to use the *if* statement to compare the innerText of two variables and whether their scores match or not. But it's not working.

Here's the Javascript and HTML code I've written.

```js
const p1Score = document.querySelector("#p1Score")
const p2Score = document.querySelector("#p2Score")

const increaseP1Score = document.querySelector("#increaseP1Score")
const increaseP2Score = document.querySelector("#increaseP2Score")
const resetScore = document.querySelector("#resetScore")

const scoreKeeper = document.querySelector("#scoreKeeper")

increaseP1Score.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    p1Score.innerText++
    // if (p1Score.innerText == 5 && p1Score.innerText > p2Score.innerText) {
    // console.log("Here it works!")

})
increaseP2Score.addEventListener('click', function() {
    p2Score.innerText++
})
resetScore.addEventListener('click', function() {
    p1Score.innerText = 0;
    p2Score.innerText = 0;
})

if (p1Score.innerText == 5 && p1Score.innerText > p2Score.innerText) {
    console.log("Working!")
}
```

```html
 <div id="container">
        <header id="header">
            <h1 id="scoreKeeper">Current Score: <span id="p1Score">0</span> to <span id="p2Score">1</span></h1>
        </header>
        <footer id="footer">
            <button id="increaseP1Score">+1 Player One</button>
            <button id="increaseP2Score">+1 Player Two</button>
            <button id="resetScore">Reset</button>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

You'll see a comment in my JS code. When I try to compare the values there, it somehow works. But I don't know why it doesn't work outside the event listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    const p1Score = document.querySelector("#p1Score")
    const p2Score = document.querySelector("#p2Score")

    const increaseP1Score = document.querySelector("#increaseP1Score")
    const increaseP2Score = document.querySelector("#increaseP2Score")
    const resetScore = document.querySelector("#resetScore")

    const scoreKeeper = document.querySelector("#scoreKeeper")

    increaseP1Score.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        p1Score.innerText++
        checkScore();
        // if (p1Score.innerText == 5 && p1Score.innerText > p2Score.innerText) {
        // console.log("Here it works!")

    })
    increaseP2Score.addEventListener('click', function() {
        p2Score.innerText++
        checkScore();
    })
    resetScore.addEventListener('click', function() {
        p1Score.innerText = 0;
        p2Score.innerText = 0;
    })

    function checkScore(){
        if (p1Score.innerText == 5 && p1Score.innerText > p2Score.innerText) {
            //console.log("Working!")
            alert("working!");
        }
    }
```

```html
     <div id="container">
            <header id="header">
                <h1 id="scoreKeeper">Current Score: <span id="p1Score">0</span> to <span id="p2Score">1</span></h1>
            </header>
            <footer id="footer">
                <button id="increaseP1Score">+1 Player One</button>
                <button id="increaseP2Score">+1 Player Two</button>
                <button id="resetScore">Reset</button>
            </footer>
        </div>
```

Your if statement is just running once when the page loads. You could put the functionality... in a function like `checkScore()` above and call it when you increment the scores. This is more re-usable and a better solution to hard-coding it in each incrementer.